# How to check for Internet Connectivity on API 30 or higher?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile

I want to check Internet connection using Network Capabilities but it is giving me this error:

> Must be one of: NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_MMS,
> NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_SUPL,
> NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_DUN,
> NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_FOTA,
> NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_IMS,
> NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_CBS,
> NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_WIFI_P2P,
> NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_IA,
> NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_RCS,
> NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_XCAP,
> NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_EIMS,
> NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_METERED,
> NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET,
> NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_RESTRICTED,
> NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_TRUSTED,
> NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_VPN,
> NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED,
> NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_CAPTIVE_PORTAL,
> NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_ROAMING,
> NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_FOREGROUND,
> NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_CONGESTED,
> NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_SUSPENDED, NetworkCapab...
> [truncated]

My code:

```
fun checkInternetConnection(context : Context) : Boolean{
    val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(
        Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

    val network = connectivityManager.activeNetwork?: return false
    val activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)?: return false

    return when{
        activeNetwork.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
        activeNetwork.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
        activeNetwork.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
        else -> false
    }
}
```

}

I tried to fix it with Android Studio's auto-correction, but instead of writing the control code I wanted, it changed it with a different code.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `activeNetwork.hasTransport(...)` as you are using TRANSPORT_ constants?

Comment: Also, please bear in mind that none of this tells you if the phone has an Internet connection (as your question title implies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this to check if device indeed has connection

```
fun isConnected(context: Context):Boolean{
        val cManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val nCapabilities = cManager.getNetworkCapabilities(cManager.activeNetwork)
        return nCapabilities != null
    }
```

it works for me, you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

in Code

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
try {
    InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com"); 
    //You can replace it with your name
        return !ipAddr.equals("");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

//return boolean value if network available

```
    private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
}
```